# Rake Command not working after upgrade rails and ruby version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

I am getting an error when i am running any sort of rake command , it is showing me

rake aborted!
**no such file to load -- config/environment**

I am trying to upgrade the ruby version from ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.11 to rails 3.0.9 and when i am trying to start the server it is showing me

**Value assigned to config.time_zone not recognized.Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding appropriate time zone names. (RuntimeError)**

I am using RVM for this upgrade

**ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]**

**rails -v
Rails 3.0.9**

Comment: `echo $TZ`, `echo rake -D time`, post the config.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace from your rails server start and rake attempt (the first 10 or so lines usually suffice). Please edit your question, or comment, don't create answers to elaborate on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just upgrade from Rails 2 to 3 without some rather extensive preparation. All hell will break loose. Check out these Railscasts for starters:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

There might be newer resources out there. I'd also suggest to upgrade first ruby and then Rails, or vice versa, not both at the same time. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0):

Peepcode Rails 3 Upgrade Handbook [PDF](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf)

Rails Core suggestions: [Plugin](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) to run checks on your Rails 2.x/3.x to check for obvious upgrade points on the path to 3.0.